# Boost.Python - undefined symbols error even though the lib files are linked

Tags: xcode, boost, boost-python

I'm testing Boost.Python and have run into some issues.

I managed to complete the "Hello World" example without a glitch (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html) - everything compiled and I was able to use the .so properly in Python.

However, as soon as I introduced classes into my test file (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html), the compiler started screaming

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "boost::python::objects::function_object(boost::python::objects::py_function const&, std::__1::pair<boost::python::detail::keyword const*, boost::python::detail::keyword const*> const&)", referenced from:
          boost::python::api::object boost::python::detail::make_function_aux<void (World::*)(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector3<void, World&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, mpl_::int_<0> >(void (World::*)(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >), boost::python::default_call_policies const&, boost::mpl::vector3<void, World&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > const&, std::__1::pair<boost::python::detail::keyword const*, boost::python::detail::keyword const*> const&, mpl_::int_<0>) in SHLibPy.o
          boost::python::api::object boost::python::detail::make_function_aux<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > (World::*)(), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector2<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, World&>, mpl_::int_<0> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > (World::*)(), boost::python::default_call_policies const&, boost::mpl::vector2<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, World&> const&, std::__1::pair<boost::python::detail::keyword const*, boost::python::detail::keyword const*> const&, mpl_::int_<0>) in SHLibPy.o
          boost::python::api::object boost::python::detail::make_function_aux<void (*)(_object*), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector2<void, _object*>, mpl_::int_<0> >(void (*)(_object*), boost::python::default_call_policies const&, boost::mpl::vector2<void, _object*> const&, std::__1::pair<boost::python::detail::keyword const*, boost::python::detail::keyword const*> const&, mpl_::int_<0>) in SHLibPy.o
      "boost::python::objects::register_dynamic_id_aux(boost::python::type_info, std::__1::pair<void*, boost::python::type_info> (*)(void*))", referenced from:
          void boost::python::objects::register_dynamic_id<World>(World*) in SHLibPy.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It seems to suggest that the lib files are not linked, but I've included them in XCode[image: Xcode]

Am I missing something? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out why. Turns out that I'm using the standard library with C++11 support. To fix the issue, I rebuilt boost using brew as follows

```
    brew -v install --with-icu --build-from-source --with-c++11 boost
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Trying your solution now.  Takes a while to rebuild :-(

Comment: A `Makefile` or `Jamroot`  would have helped... This didn't work for me